# Proof on Multiplication Funtion's Continuity.

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose $(X, \mathcal{T}_X)$ is a topological space, and that $f_1 :  X
>  \to \mathbb{R}, f_2: X \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions. prove
>   the multiplication function  $$f_1f_2 : X \to
>  \mathbb{R},\hspace{0.25cm}f_1f_2 (x) = f_1(x)f_2(x)$$ is continous

My thoughts: need to show $$ (f_1f_2)^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{T}_X,  \forall  U \in \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}  $$ ($\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ )
$$(f_1f_2)^{-1}(U) = \{ x \in X:   f_1f_2(x) \in U\} =\{x \in X:   f_1(x)f_2(x) \in U \} $$ Since $U$ open, then, there is $\delta$ such that $(f_1f_2(x) - \delta, f_1f_2(x) + \delta) \subset U$
 But I don't know how to continue, and no idea how to utilize the continuity of $f_1, f_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
use the fact that 
$$ g : X \to \mathbb{R}^2 \, , \,
x \mapsto (f_1(x),f_2(x))$$
and
$$ h : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} \, , \,
(x,y) \mapsto xy$$
are continous.

Comment: oh,  thinking $f_1f_2$ as a composition of two continuous function. Omg, I can't believe myself spent hours trying to do useless things like find out basis elements or union of open sets for such question... ;(